# aria-expanded does not switch to true on clicking , so dropdown is not working

Tags: bootstrap-4

The powerOffn image is a dropdown which will shows sign out on clicking. But the dropdown is not working.
I am using Bootstrap4. The aria-expanded does not switch to true on clicking.
I have tried adding aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false" but does not work.
I also tried adding id and aria-labelledby as suggested in another post. What changes should I make?

````
<li class="nav-item dropdown user-menu">
  <a href="#" class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">
     <img src="~/dist/img/poweroffn.png"  class=" user-image img-circle elevation-2"/>
  </a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-lg dropdown-menu-right">
       <!-- Menu Body -->
        <li class="user-body">
          <a href="/account/logout" class="btn btn-default btn-flat float-right">Sign out</a>
        <!-- /.row -->
        </li>
  </ul>
</li>
    ```
````